# How to Troubleshoot Cause of Memory Errors

Tags: memory, motherboard, troubleshooting

Hope someone can give me an idea of how to resolve this issue short of replacing the whole machine.

**Background/History**

I have an ASUS P8Z68-M Pro MB / G620 CPU / 16GB DDR3 1333MHz CL 9-9-9-24 DRAM.  The system is about 4 years old, and it had memory errors about 2 years ago. I bought new RAM and RMA'd the bad set to keep for spare.

Last week I noticed some weird errors in FreeNAS (which have been happening for some time), so I took the machine down and started running Memtest86+ v4.2, and found an easily reproducible error in one of the DIMMs at address 0019bd12878.

First time memory failed on Pass 1, Test 2 error bit was 00010000 - bit expected was 0, but 1 was read.

Second time error was on Pass 1, Test 1 - error bit was 00020000, again 0 expected, one read.

Problem was very easy to reproduce - Put the bad DIMM in a different slot for the two different tests - failed both times.

**The problem**

I replaced the bad RAM with the spare RAM from the first RMA.  Brand new Patriot VIPER DDR3 1600MHz CL9-9-9-24 which I set up to run at 1333MHz in the BIOS.  (G620 won't take the higher multiplier.)  Did XMP in the BIOS, and then set the clock speed to 1333.

I now have a weird situation with the replacement.

This Ran fine for just over 24 hours, then I started getting a few errors at 0004d2fxxxx.  (Range of addresses - program only shows a few on the screen and I don't have a printer hooked up to it, or any way to capture more details.)

Without taking down the machine I changed the Memtest86+ settings to spot test the area that was reporting the errors, and got about 4500 errors very quickly.  All the errors reported with Test 8 "Random Patterns"

When I tried to reproduce and localize the problem by pulling one of the two DIMMs, and the errors stopped.  So the power cycle and/or reinserting the other DIMM cleared the problem.

I went back to the original configuration and so far it has been running error free for over 37 hours.  Which makes it less likely to be a simple thermal problem.

**Questions**

1. Any suggestions on how I can localize this problem?
2. Any other test programs I should run that might help?
3. Is this more likely to be a memory problem, motherboard problem (or even  CPU chip or Power supply issue)?

Any suggestions or input would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This may be hard to clarify but it seems, based on the information you provided, that you're underclocking your RAM.  DIMMs require a constant refresh cycle and if it gets too low, it will cause the data to become corrupted, which I suspect may be the case.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am clocking 1600MHz at 1333Mhz.  I was told that this was no problem to do (maybe that is not the case-If so, I'd appreciate comments.)

Update: the system is now over 47.5 hours of continuous tests with no errors.

Comment: It depends on the actual memory chip's specifications.

Comment: Can you tell me what to check... I'll see if I can find chip specs.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but would it not show a more consistent pattern of errors if that were the problem?  It's now up to 20 complete passes and 59.5 hours of successful tests.  What I don't get is why a consistent pattern of errors that goes away.  Mechanical connection changes or power cycle appears to be what cleared the problem.  Wonder if it's contact oxidization.

Comment: Based on what you did to solve it, it does point towards a physical connection issue.

Comment: Just noticed there were a few BIOS updates for the motherboard, and a couple of them were to.Improve system stability./ Improve memory compatibility. I flashed the BIOS and restarted the test which has been running for about 1.75 hours and successfully completed one complete pass . I wonder if BIOS issues would cause intermittent failure, or if failure would be more consistent with a BIOS problem?

Comment: I suppose that's what they meant by the information you just provided, so hopefully it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell for sure if I've got a solution or not.  Found and applied a BIOS update that is purported to improve stability and memory comparability.

So far after applying the patch the system has been running successfully for almost 48 hours.  At this point I don't know if I've solved the problem, or just haven't found what causes it to fail.